# SElinux stopping LVS from working with https

Tags: wget, lvs

LVS/piranha is setup and trying to get it to balance https instead of http.  Setup https testing with wget - idea from [this link](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.piranha/month=20101101).  Works when I do it at the command prompt.  With SELinux enforcing, the wget fails to run due to the lack of access to /dev/random.  (Error - Could not seed PRNG; consider using --random-file. Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.)

wget runs as system_u:system_r:piranha_lvs_t:s0 but the file/device /dev/random has system_u:object_r:random_device_t:s0   Also, wget is trying to getattr and read.

How do you allow wget to use /dev/random so it will do ssl?

Answer (score 0):

1. ran audit2allow to on the logs to find out what needed to be changed
2. to get audit2allow, you need to install setroubleshoot via yum, at least on CentOS
3. When I ran it audit2allow, said it that piranha_lvs_t needed access to random_device_t:chr_file both read and getattr
4. and audit2allow said that the boolean global_ssp would solve the problem - i.e. setsebool global_ssp on

PS: yes, I am answering my own question.

Comment: That's no problem, but please mark it as accepted answer.